# Is there a try-except-finally equivalent to "async with"

Tags: python

Instead of using

```
async with db.open() as conn:
```

is there a `try`-`except`-`finally` equivalent to this?

I want the object that i get from `db.open` so that I can pass it to other places in my class without using `with` statements in every function. Is this possible?

The requirement is for the code to function like this:

```
async try:     
    connection = db.open()   
    await someOperations(connection, ...)

finally:
    connection.close()
```

### Edit:

For clarity:
Im using `sqlalchemy`'s `async engine`

My code looks something like this rn:

```
async with self.__engine.connect() as connection:
```

The goal would be to have code that can function in this manner:

```
try:
   connection = self.__engine.connect():
   await someFn(connection, ....args) #someFn is also async
```

The issue here is that I'm getting an error about calling `connection` in a non-async block
The code is inside an async func:

```
async def myfunc:
   // code from above
```

Comment: If your `db.open()` is a coroutine, you don't need `async try`, but just `connection = await db.open()` in a regular `try` block.

Answer (score 2):

it depends on what `db.open` is, generally speaking

```py
async with manager as ctx:
    ...
```

equals to

```py
try:
    ctx = await manager.__aenter__()
    ...
finally:
   await manager.__aexit__()
```

so the equivalent form is

```py
try:
    manager = db.open()
    conn = await manager.__aenter__()
    ...
finally:
   await manager.__aexit__()
```

Comment: I've updated the question with a few more details.
Will try this out

Comment: Thank you @YaGregor 
This helped me look in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit more digging into sqlalchemy's async engine source code and this seems to work:

```py
try:
  connection = self.__engine.connect()
  await connection.__aenter__()
  await myfunc(connection, ...args)
except Exception as e:
  # handle exception
finally:
  await connection.close()
```